# How to disable autoopen internal webbrowser after run webapp?

Tags: java, eclipse-wtp, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

When I run web app on server in STS internal web browser opens. I want to disable this but I don't know where can I do this.

Answer (score 18):

[Eldelshell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48869/eldelshell) already sort of answered this, but I think a little more info might help other people. He's correct about going to **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Web Browser** and creating a new external external browser configuration. This will only work with an executable, though. Thus, entering `/dev/null` in the "Location" field won't work. What to put there depends on which type of operating system you're on, but basically you want to specifiy a command that doesn't do much. I use:

- for *nix based systems: `/bin/true` (does nothing, successfully: [reference](http://linux.die.net/man/1/true))
- for Windows systems: `cmd /c` (spawns a shell and terminates immediately: [reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771320(v=ws.11).aspx))

Here's what it looks like to add the web browser configuration in Eclipse Neon. Note that after adding the configuration, you also need to activate it by checking the adjacent checkbox in the parent dialog.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this disable the ability to open a web link inside eclipse? Can I only stop the auto open instead of disable the whole external web browser function?

Answer (score 1):

For Mac,

Go to Window->Preferences->General->Web Browser; create a new "browser" pointing to /usr/bin/true.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Window->Preferences->General->Web Browser** and select an external browser. If it still annoys you, create a new "browser" pointing to */dev/null*