# Eclipse auto-opens a web browser when started with a deployed WAR file

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, war

I have my war project that I run on Tomcat server in Eclipse. Everything is going just great, except for Eclipse auto opens a web browser. I want to disable it, but I cant find how.

Anybody knows if it's possible?

Comment: Probable duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007981/how-to-disable-autoopen-internal-webbrowser-after-run-webapp

Comment: oo thanks but no answer there... i guess there is no solution for this...

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten used to redeploying via the Servers tab (from there, right-click your server, hit Publish or Restart) instead of the Run button/menu. That way it doesn't open the tab.

Comment: "hit Publish or Restart .." or Debug for debugging.